# Mapping ASM disks to Physical Disks on AIX based on Major, Minor numbers

Tags: scripting

I wrote this shell script to map ASM devices to Physical Devices on an AIX box. But, I'm getting output which is not intended and I'm unable to debug it. I request your help with this. Details are as below.

ASM Devices:

```
test160 orainfra +ASM1 >> ls -l /dev | grep orainfra
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 35 Jan 23 01:16 ebs_arch_31
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 36 Jan 23 01:16 ebs_arch_32
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 37 Jan 23 01:15 ebs_arch_33
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 38 Jan 23 01:16 ebs_arch_34
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 39 Jan 22 20:01 ebs_data1_31
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 40 Jan 23 19:39 ebs_data1_32
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 41 Jan 10 19:39 ebs_data1_33
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 42 Dec 25 02:22 ebs_data1_34
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 43 Jan 24 07:34 ebs_data1_35
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 44 Jan 25 07:41 ebs_data1_36
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 45 Jan 25 19:44 ebs_data1_37
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 46 Jan  1 19:49 ebs_data1_38
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 47 Jan 22 09:23 ebs_data1_39
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 48 Jan 15 07:01 ebs_data1_40
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 49 Jan 23 07:54 ebs_data1_41
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 50 Jan 22 09:13 ebs_data1_42
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 51 Jan 22 09:13 ebs_data1_43
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 10 Jun 17 2019  ebs_gg_data31
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 11 Jun 17 2019  ebs_gg_data32
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 12 Oct 21 16:20 ebs_gg_data33
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 13 Oct 21 16:19 ebs_gg_data34
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34,  5 Jun 17 2019  ebs_ocr11
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34,  6 Jun 17 2019  ebs_ocr12
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 52 Jul 23 2019  ebs_redoa_35
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 53 Jan 25 22:28 ebs_redoa_36
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 54 Jan 25 22:28 ebs_redoa_37
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 55 Jan 23 01:15 ebs_redoa_38
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 56 Jul 12 2019  ebs_temp_35
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 57 Jan 22 09:13 ebs_temp_36
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 58 Oct 21 18:23 ebs_temp_37
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34, 59 Jan 22 09:13 ebs_temp_38
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34,  7 Jan 26 05:25 ebs_voting11
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34,  8 Jan 26 02:02 ebs_voting12
crw-rw-r--    1 orainfra dba          34,  9 Jun 17 2019  ebs_voting13
test160 orainfra +ASM1 >>
```

PHYSICAL Devices:

```
test160 orainfra +ASM1 >> ls -l /dev | grep rhdiskpower
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34,  0 Jun 17 2019  rhdiskpower0
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34,  1 Jun 17 2019  rhdiskpower1
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 10 Jun 17 2019  rhdiskpower10
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 11 Jun 17 2019  rhdiskpower11
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 12 Jun 17 2019  rhdiskpower12
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 13 Jun 17 2019  rhdiskpower13
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34,  2 Jun 17 2019  rhdiskpower2
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34,  3 Jun 17 2019  rhdiskpower3
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 34 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower34
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 35 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower35
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 36 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower36
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 37 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower37
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 38 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower38
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 39 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower39
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34,  4 Jun 17 2019  rhdiskpower4
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 40 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower40
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 41 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower41
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 42 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower42
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 43 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower43
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 44 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower44
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 45 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower45
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 46 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower46
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 47 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower47
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 48 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower48
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 49 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower49
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34,  5 Jun 17 2019  rhdiskpower5
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 50 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower50
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 51 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower51
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 52 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower52
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 53 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower53
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 54 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower54
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 55 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower55
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 56 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower56
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 57 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower57
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 58 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower58
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34, 59 Jul 10 2019  rhdiskpower59
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34,  6 Jun 17 2019  rhdiskpower6
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34,  7 Jun 17 2019  rhdiskpower7
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34,  8 Jun 17 2019  rhdiskpower8
crw-rw----    1 root     system       34,  9 Jun 17 2019  rhdiskpower9
test160 orainfra +ASM1 >>
```

Script:

```
ls -l /dev | grep orainfra > /home/orainfra/TEST/asm_disks_8.lst
input_file="/home/orainfra/TEST/asm_disks_8.lst"
while IFS= read -r line
do
major=`echo "$line" | awk '{ print $5 }'`
minor=`echo "$line" | awk '{ print $6 }'`
asm_disk=`echo "$line" | awk '{ print $10 }'`
physical_disk=`ls -l /dev | grep rhdiskpower | grep "$major *$minor" | awk '{ print $10 }'`
echo "The ASM disk: '$asm_disk' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: '$physical_disk' " >> asm_physical_disks_mapping_8.lst
done <"$input_file"
```

Output:

```
The ASM disk: 'ebs_arch_31' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower35'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_arch_32' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower36'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_arch_33' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower37'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_arch_34' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower38'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_data1_31' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower39'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_data1_32' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower40'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_data1_33' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower41'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_data1_34' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower42'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_data1_35' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower43'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_data1_36' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower44'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_data1_37' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower45'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_data1_38' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower46'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_data1_39' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower47'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_data1_40' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower48'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_data1_41' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower49'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_data1_42' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower50'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_data1_43' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower51'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_gg_data31' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower10'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_gg_data32' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower11'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_gg_data33' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower12'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_gg_data34' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower13'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_ocr11' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower5
rhdiskpower50
rhdiskpower51
rhdiskpower52
rhdiskpower53
rhdiskpower54
rhdiskpower55
rhdiskpower56
rhdiskpower57
rhdiskpower58
rhdiskpower59'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_ocr12' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower6'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_redoa_35' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower52'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_redoa_36' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower53'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_redoa_37' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower54'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_redoa_38' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower55'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_temp_35' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower56'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_temp_36' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower57'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_temp_37' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower58'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_temp_38' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower59'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_voting11' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower7'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_voting12' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower8'
The ASM disk: 'ebs_voting13' is mapped to PHYSICAL Disk: 'rhdiskpower9'
```

Not able to identify why the below is being captured in the output:

```
rhdiskpower50
rhdiskpower51
rhdiskpower52
rhdiskpower53
rhdiskpower54
rhdiskpower55
rhdiskpower56
rhdiskpower57
rhdiskpower58
rhdiskpower59
```

Regards,
RA

Comment: What connects the two lists of devices? (Guess the major+minor being the same.)

Comment: Not sure. But the ASM devices are logical. And yes, the Major and Minor of both should be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the script gets to `ebs_ocr11` the variables will be `major="34,"` and `minor="5". So the`grep command searching for the correct line from the `rhdiskpower` list will be:

... | grep rhdiskpower | grep "34, *5" | awk ...

Since the regular expression does not specify that there should be whitespace after the `$minor` variable, the expression will match not only `34,  5` but also `34, 50`, `34, 51` ... all the way to `34, 59`. So `grep` will output multiple lines, and `awk` will remove all but the 10th element from each line, but will keep them as separate lines.

The value of the `$physical_disk` ends up being a string that contains line feeds: `"rhdiskpower5\nrhdiskpower50\nrhdiskpower51\n..."` etc.

### The fix

I'd suggest modifying this line:

```
physical_disk=`ls -l /dev | grep rhdiskpower | grep "$major *$minor" | awk '{ print $10 }'`
```

to this:

```
physical_disk=`ls -l /dev | grep "$major *$minor .* rhdiskpower[0-9]*$" | awk '{ print $10 }'`
```

This also removes one extra `grep`.

If AIX `ls` command uses TABs instead of spaces in its output, you might have to replace some of the spaces in the regular expression with `\t` or similar.

### Other suggestions

The ASM disk name should be fairly easy to read from the disk itself. If you look at the public descriptions of [ASM metadata block header](http://asmsupportguy.blogspot.com/2013/09/asm-metadata-blocks.html) and [ASM disk header](http://asmsupportguy.blogspot.com/2011/08/asm-disk-header.html) located immediately after that and calculate the offsets, you'll find that an ASM disk is fairly easy to identify:

- at offset 0x0020 from the beginning of the ASM device, there should be a constant string `ORCLDISK`. Immediately after the string there may be a platform-specific driver information string, or just a null terminator.
- at offset 0x0048 you'll find the name of the ASM disk, null-terminated.
- at offset 0x0068 there is the name of the ASM disk group the disk currently belongs to, also null-terminated.
- at offset 0x0088 there is the name of the ASM failgroup the disk belongs to, likewise null-terminated.

If you had root access and a command that could read a string at a fixed offset on a block device, armed with this information you could simply loop through all the `rhdiskpower*` devices, check if each of them is an ASM disk, and read the identification information if it is. This might offer a stronger way to map ASM disks instead of parsing the `ls` output.

Comment: Thanks a ton telcoM. Worked like  a charm. And Thank you very much the explanation. Don't have the root access to test what you mentioned.